# Overflow: hidden not working when position: absolute

Tags: css

I am trying to build a UI component which's idea is to have 2 overlapping sections (the first one has to cover the second) and to expand the first one with a draggable element. I am providing you with a demo:

http://codepen.io/LazarGeorgiev/pen/yOPbmx

The problem is that I want the elements not to reposition when I resizing the first element and in order to achieve this I use `position:absolute;` which apparently brakes my `overflow:hidden;`

I checked some posts on StackOverflow where I should use `position:relative;` on an outer `<div>` element, which doesn't work here, because it brakes the `position:absolute;`

So my question is how to make it hide when resizing without repositioning the elements inside.

P.S. the innermost `<div>` is `.the-content` and the outer is `.first`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use a fixed with ? If yes the code below should work for you.

```js
(function($)
{
    $sectionheight = $('.covered').height();
    $.fn.coveringBad = function(options)
    {
        var settings = $.extend(
        {
            marginY: $sectionheight / 2,
            marginX: 30,
            setX: 30,
            setY: 30,
            direction: "horizontal"
        }, options);
        return this.each(function()
        {
            // Initialization
            ////////////////////////////////
            var $this = $(this),
                $changeable = $this.find('>.changeable'),
                $handle = $this.find('>.handle'),
                width = $this.innerWidth(),
                height = $this.innerHeight(),
                pos_x = null,
                startX = null,
                min_left = settings.marginX,
                max_left = width - settings.marginX,
                min_top = settings.marginY,
                max_top = height - settings.marginY,
                setX = settings.setX,
                setY = settings.setY;
            $changeable.height($this.height());
            if (setX < min_left)
            {
                setX = min_left;
            }
            if (setY < min_top)
            {
                setY = min_top;
            }
            $handle.css('left', setX);
            $handle.css('top', setY);
            // Direction
            //////////////////////////////////
            $changeable.width(setX);
            $changeable.css('border-right', '1px dashed #FFF');
          
            // Dragging Bad
            //////////////////////////////////
            $handle.on('mousedown', function(event)
            {
                event.preventDefault();
                $handle.addClass('draggable');
                pos_x = parseInt($handle.css('left'));
                startX = event.pageX;
            });
            $(document).on('mouseup', function(event)
            {
                $handle.removeClass('draggable');
            });
            $this.bind('mousemove', dragger);

            function dragger(e)
                {
                    var left = pos_x + (e.pageX - startX);
                    if (left < min_left) left = min_left;
                    else if (left > max_left) left = max_left;
                    $('.draggable').css('left', left);
                    if ($('.draggable').length)
                    {
                        $changeable.width(left);
                    }
                }
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
$('.covered').coveringBad();
```

```css
.covered {
  position: relative;
 width  : 600px;
 height : 400px;
 margin : 50px auto;
 border:1px solid black;
}

.changeable {
  position: static;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.first {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:white;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.the-content{
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.second{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  margin-left:50px;
  padding:10px;
}
.second h3 {
  margin-left:450px;
}
.logo{
  width:70px;
  margin-right:15px;
  margin-bottom:15px;
}
.handle {
 position: absolute;
 width : 46px;
 height: 46px;
 margin-left  : -23px;
 margin-top   : -23px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background-color: #fff;
 text-align : center;
  cursor:ew-resize;
  z-index:2;
}

.handle span {
 display : inline-block;
 margin : 15px 1px 0;
 color : #000;
 transition : 0.4s ease-out;
}

.handle:hover, .handle:active {
 background-color: #555;
}

.handle:hover span, .handle:active span {
 color : #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="covered">
  <div class="second">
    <h3> Clients</h3>
    <img class="logo" src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphicthumb/nike_logo_30021.jpg">
    <img class="logo" src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphicthumb/nike_logo_30021.jpg">
    <img class="logo" src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphicthumb/nike_logo_30021.jpg">
    <img class="logo" src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphicthumb/nike_logo_30021.jpg">
    <img class="logo" src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphicthumb/nike_logo_30021.jpg">
    <img class="logo" src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphicthumb/nike_logo_30021.jpg">
     
  </div>
  
  <div class="handle">
    <span class="left icon-chevron-left"></span>
    <span class="right icon-chevron-right"/></span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="changeable">
    <div class="first">
      <div class="the-content">
        <h3>Partners</h3>
        <img class="logo" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/20/Adidas_Logo.svg/2000px-Adidas_Logo.svg.png">
        <img class="logo" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/20/Adidas_Logo.svg/2000px-Adidas_Logo.svg.png">    <img class="logo" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/20/Adidas_Logo.svg/2000px-Adidas_Logo.svg.png">    <img class="logo" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/20/Adidas_Logo.svg/2000px-Adidas_Logo.svg.png">    <img class="logo" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/20/Adidas_Logo.svg/2000px-Adidas_Logo.svg.png">    <img class="logo" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/20/Adidas_Logo.svg/2000px-Adidas_Logo.svg.png">    <img class="logo" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/20/Adidas_Logo.svg/2000px-Adidas_Logo.svg.png">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Really good point. The only thing is that it would not be responsive, but if we set the width of the element with the width of the whole element via jquery it will work. Well done my fellow and thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your logic in js is wrong. Your Nike logos are only hidden because of the z-index and not your overflow hidden.

Comment: otherwise how can you hide an element under the other?